# every time with play run slick recreated database

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I am using play and using slick . After migrating to slick
when ever i am starting the server with play run  each time play tries to drop and recreate tables saying
 "Database 'default' needs evolution!"

Even though there are not changes to my DB and server. Is there any way to configure this so that tables wont get dropped each time.

using play 2.1.0 and https://github.com/freekh/play-slick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable evolutions you can either update your configuration file with: 

`applyEvolutions.default=false`
 
or add it on the command line: 

`play run -DapplyEvolutions.default=true`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably play-slick creating a `conf/evolutions/default/1.sql` which it only does if it doesn’t exist, and if it isn’t disabled with the configuration `evolutionplugin=false`. I would guess that you are still changing your table mappings in the Scala code, which means that the database changes.

The solution as `applyEvolutions.default=false`, as Fredrik already said, or to maintain your own evolutions file so that play-slick won't generate one.

Answer (score 0):

Look to /conf if there is /evolutions directory with database evolutions and try to delete this evolutions folder.

Comment: Even if i deleted its getting created